# Adding extra input controls on 'CombinedSignInAndSignUp' Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm trying to add extra input controls on 'CombinedSignInAndSignUp' orchestration step (This is the first combined sign-up / sign-in page).
It looks like it's stripping away any other control but the username and password field. Even if I set any other controls it treats them 'username' and 'password' controls.

Has anyone tried this? I'd appreciate your guidance on this.

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: Can you share how you add the extra input controls? Please add any code.

Comment: It is not possible to add extra control in Unified SignIn page.  But you can add these controls in other technical profile and add them as separate orchestration step.

Comment: This is really frustrating for us who want the password reset link (embedded) but are not able to make changes to the controls.